# How to draw a geometry shape exactly where mouse is clicked in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, drawing, mouseevent

I am trying to draw a circle exactly where mouse is clicked, but circle is drawn not at exact position. Please let me know what needs to be corrected in the code:

```
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 1000 );


            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();


                if( event.which == 1) { // left mouse click

                   // x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                   // y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 + 1;

                    var x = event.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
                    var y = event.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer
                    var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

                    x = ((x - rect.left) - window.innerWidth/2)/(window.innerWidth/2);
                    y = (window.innerHeight/2 - (y - rect.top))/(window.innerHeight/2);

                    var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 20, 32 );
                    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x65A8FF } );
                    circle = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    //circle.position.x = x*window.innerWidth*1.23;
                    //circle.position.y = y*765; 

                    circle.position.x = x*window.innerWidth;
                    circle.position.y = y*window.innerHeight;

                    scene.add( circle );
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that it's assuming 3D `x y` coordinates are connected to pixel coordinates without taking the camera's perspective or depth into account. With a perspective camera, the deeper the point goes, the greater its x, y coords will be. You need to set a depth (z) for the points to stop at. Additionally, if your camera moves or rotates, your `X, Y` coordinates will not work.

I recommend you use a [`THREE.Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster), which performs all those camera projection calculations for you (the docs have an example of its usage at the top of the page). You can see that approach in action [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter).

The way it works is:

1. You create a plane for the raycaster to hit (this is your depth).
2. Create a raycast with Raycaster.setFromCamera()
3. Read back the position where the ray hits the plane.
4. Use this position to create your geometry.